# Is there any way to schedule Log4Net to take log from project automatically?

Tags: c#, log4net

I used `Log4Net` in my project (It's a `Windows Service`) for logging, i want to know is there any way to automatically rollover the log to a new file when a certain condition is met ?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to log at specific times?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own logging appender, e.g. by inheriting from the appender that you want, and implement your scheduling logic in there.

Something along the lines of this (untested):

```
public class ScheduledAppender : FileAppender
{
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
       if (SchedulingLogic.ItIsTimeToLog) // Your scheduling logic here
       {
           base.Append(loggingEvent);
       }
    }
}
```

In order to configure the schedule you can define custom configuration attributes for your appender, as shown here:

[Getting values from Log4Net configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081242/getting-values-from-log4net-configuration)

This link should provide you with an entry point to writing your own appender
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406634/Creating-a-custom-log-net-appender

Comment: Is there any way to do that without implementing our own logging appender?

Comment: An alternative would be to wrap log4net in a custom logger and implement the scheduling there. However, I'd look into using an appender in order to make the logging configurable and flexible.